# What does it mean when a Mercurial/TortoiseHg graph line trails off with no dot?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I work on a team with 3 other developers and for the most part we're all working on the same Mercurial repository in anonymous branches and periodically merging with the default branch. Yesterday one of the other developers decided to update to a previous revision and continue working from there. After committing his changes and then pulling and merging we noticed some strange behavior with the graph (see image below) in TortoiseHg that we hadn't ever seen before. Basically we have some graph lines that don't end with a dot but just trail off and never merge back into any other branch. What does this mean in plain English?

[image: Mercurial/TortoiseHg graph]

UPDATE: I'm leaning toward "bug", but in the latest graph I have a similar kind of line that weaves its way through the entire graph and doesn't seem to serve any purpose at all. Here it can be seen in light blue to the left of changeset 0 at the very bottom of the graph.

[image]

UPDATE: ASCII output from hg glog appears below. TortoiseHg graph has unconnected lines around rev 281, but it looks fine here. So...bug?

```
@    297 277f72eb6da3
|\
| o  296 eb2505095090
| |
o |  295 7f44b8354252
| |
| o  294 b4b7e3fa683a
| |
| o    293 e2e16967987f
| |\
+---o  292 e5d13c14417e
| |
| o  291 f12a6a3fa06a
| |
| o  290 ea93c6fe6244
| |
| o  289 fbc2e750a98d
| |
| | o  288 987fd06bad0d
| | |
o | |    287 b91bd794ca84
|\ \ \
| o | |  286 063968c4a406
| |\| |
| o | |  285 ed2b17250a34
| | | |
| +---o  284 6e4bee3dbe42
| | |
| | o  283 5ff74bb8925f
| | |
| | o  282 4371e9119ca4
| | |
| | o  281 74b9630e724a
| | |
o | |  280 843d53c8f5a3
| | |
o | |    279 7280384bafb5
|\ \ \
| o | |  278 f8c7d6448dd7
| | | |
| | | o  277 ab0defa17a42
| | | |
| | | o  276 b81b3f585b61
| | | |
| | | o  275 8181738fc128
| | |/|
| | o |    274 15d1edd01930
| | |\ \
| | | o |  273 20d28e88309e
| | | | |
| | | o |  272 638202667d79
| | | | |
| | | o |  271 f5b721732919
| | | | |
| | | o |  270 3ed4dc310ef9
| | | | |
| | | o |  269 8668b447d11a
| | | | |
| | | o |  268 5da2afe6c20f
| | | | |
| | | o |  267 a0035d7fbb0a
| | | | |
| | | o |  266 7f5cdd3785ef
| | | | |
| +---o |  265 6b33fb77d690
| | |  /
| | o |  264 85c4e24470bb
| | | |
| | o |  263 d27d32f55b9b
| | | |
| | o |  262 18ade431b8c7
| | | |
| | o |    261 11f790e11e14
| | |\ \
| | | o |  260 35f8e03564d1
| | | | |
| | | | o    259 1589883b30c7
| | | | |\
| | +-----o  258 16f7379774e6
| | | | | |
| | | | | o  257 38d632954f9f
| | | | | |
| | o | | |  256 291b3bdcc278
| | | | | |
| | o | | |  255 d2f250884ede
| | | | | |
| | o | | |  254 4fb369822248
| | | | | |
| | o-----+  253 545bf895343f
| |  / / /
| | | | o  252 c967b3b86ab4
| | | | |
| | | | o  251 0afc2bc4b457
| | | | |
+-------o  250 242c8aa8ef4c
| | | | |
| | | | o  249 aea5303af4fd
| | | | |
| | | | o  248 99c0e0e3d9f2
| | | | |
| | | o |  247 d7cd0925420d
| | |/ /
| | o |  246 cb666cc77c6a
| | | |
+---o |  245 3ea6105e3d23
| | | |
| | o |  244 b18ce1b772fa
| | | |
| | o |  243 dd9a955d89ae
| | | |
o | | |  242 da037c3ef808
| | | |
o | | |  241 a5a215bacf93
| | | |
o---+ |  240 aa4bcf158ebf
| | | |
o | | |  239 c5f3455d4bda
| | | |
| | o |  238 c5b10fd90a5a
| | | |
o---+ |  237 1434f54af390
| | | |
o | | |  236 6a80392e6889
| | | |
| | o |  235 9f427af5db3e
| | | |
o-----+  234 d364e47f38f7
| | | |
o---+ |  233 7736771453e4
 / / /
| | o  232 9355db64071a
| | |
| | o  231 8e9b6642e081
| | |
| | o  230 36c80dfbbc9b
| | |
| | o    229 4aa91fa61018
| | |\
| | | o  228 b5b061782d5d
| | | |
| | | o  227 95510065ff70
| | | |
| | | o  226 5dbbe83a797f
| | | |
| | o |  225 46fe0007cba7
| | |/
| o |    224 9d0aff36ebb1
| |\ \
| | o |  223 e0b8cd2064b6
| | | |
| | o |  222 8fdd474049a1
| | | |
+---o |  221 fb87da613f35
| | | |
| | o |  220 a1416803f165
| | | |
| | o |  219 99bb611b3c25
| | | |
| | o |  218 4251ccb7a50b
| | | |
| | o |  217 16c570465c7d
| | | |
| | o |  216 571af15a026b
| | | |
| | o |  215 7ce72afe55f8
| | | |
| | o |  214 b90ac62f3540
| | | |
| | o |  213 3644bd76aef6
| | | |
| | o |  212 a9c3f1bb1230
| | | |
| | o |  211 1110988cde8a
| | | |
| | o |  210 3ee58b526393
| | | |
| o | |  209 c386f0c3284d
|/ / /
o | |  208 82feb7ad6ac9
| | |
o | |  207 3d86176fed2f
| | |
o | |  206 a5d85dc7a37d
| | |
o | |  205 c507e4c0b02c
| | |
o | |  204 37f4277a8322
| | |
o | |  203 15e563293c07
| | |
o | |  202 b3994704a0d2
| | |
o | |  201 d618083c13be
| | |
o | |  200 2d2556ff4171
| | |
o | |    199 da90fbeddd3d
|\ \ \
| o | |  198 6f0a41ac629d
| | | |
| o | |    197 947cf457aec0
| |\ \ \
| | o | |  196 b17c092b8590
| | | | |
| | o | |    195 42af669cb779
| | |\ \ \
| | | o | |  194 c5464c4f2e06
| | | | | |
o | | | | |  193 507df365099a
|/ / / / /
o | | | |  192 a9fe0c0683f8
| | | | |
o | | | |  191 f082f83ac787
| | | | |
o-----+ |  190 d906303e387e
 / / / /
| | o |  189 4e73c2c778ae
| | | |
| | o |  188 1b1bed6cbd42
| | | |
| | o |    187 54a9d626a419
| | |\ \
| | | o |  186 c5c153dfc6af
| | | | |
| | | o |  185 664dac360636
| | | | |
| | o | |  184 cb3516daf65a
| | |\| |
| | | o |  183 be8618ea400f
| | | | |
+-----o |  182 ba3cf50882b8
| | | | |
| | | o |  181 174185b1ba35
| | | | |
| | | o |    180 9ac8a79d9e33
| | | |\ \
| | | | o |  179 e1f1aa639833
| | | | | |
| | | | o |  178 6a181fbfdfd1
| | | | | |
| | | | o |  177 f9dbe5b840e8
| | | | | |
| | | | o |  176 f8124c6d8f0d
| | | | | |
+---o | | |  175 ddadb145b45d
| |  / / /
o | | | |  174 e6a3a5be7dfb
| | | | |
o | | | |  173 6019de4fe022
|/ / / /
o | | |    172 69543cb61e07
|\ \ \ \
| o-----+  171 bb965fd8cc62
| | | | |
| | | | o  170 6f4a86f501b6
| | | | |
| o | | |  169 87049b28b2b3
| | | | |
| o-----+  168 8da5cb2b368b
| | | | |
| o | | |  167 152455050b5a
| | | | |
| | | | o    166 7ceb485c912c
| | | | |\
| | | | | o  165 a8b596b6de4c
| | | | | |
| | | | o |  164 a313f1547645
| | | | |/
| | | | o  163 a163a07da88d
| | | | |
| | | | o    162 87b0f153587f
| | | | |\
| | | | | o  161 2357d8eb4980
| | | | | |
| | | | o |  160 b1537d8a39bf
| | | | |/
| | | | o  159 8b27dae8df5d
| | | | |
| o | | |  158 de823bfc1989
| | | | |
| o | | |  157 2dd992a51584
| | | | |
| o-----+  156 60f95e4043f5
|  / / /
o | | |  155 51b8e3b4fd6a
| | | |
o | | |  154 b86455939248
|/ / /
o | |  153 e743a0f603b4
| | |
o | |  152 4b0cc0b34822
| | |
o | |  151 8d2cfa92c93c
| | |
o | |  150 06e798e33eb6
| | |
o | |  149 26e0f58a4d6c
| | |
o---+  148 65e44b7abc91
| | |
| | o    147 c63d37b9ae4c
| | |\
| | | o  146 ec2c8913a049
| | | |
| | o |  145 15329a633aee
| | | |
| | o |  144 c76ce1dbf93a
| | |\|
| | | o  143 ff84766aa577
| | | |
| | | o  142 9183686fdb8e
| | | |
| | o |  141 019500da31f1
| | |\|
| | | o  140 06a8ad379f5e
| | | |
| | o |  139 eb3c772f1001
| | |/
o | |  138 768bd3b7b6c3
| | |
o | |  137 35cf9e3d7a0c
| | |
o---+  136 f9c585b79ad9
| | |
| | o  135 b07cf920ff9c
| | |
| | o  134 6c8df987d7ea
| | |
| | o  133 30c8eef28701
| | |
o---+  132 39bc6332d845
| | |
| | o  131 8d66f4c7c74f
| | |
| | o  130 365fc4ca49e1
| | |
o | |    129 8c5cb2f4b19f
|\ \ \
| o \ \    128 467c0eff23ac
| |\ \ \
| | o | |  127 0668cb6e6242
| | | | |
o-------+  126 b7bbe1d3a2ec
|/ / / /
| | | o  125 c143bb4224ba
| | | |
o-----+  124 b42aa5b476fb
| | | |
| | | o  123 d82ef3f041c5
| | | |
o | | |  122 78c228ad9a5b
| | | |
o | | |  121 052788cf6433
| | | |
o-----+  120 244aeec899b7
| | | |
| | | o  119 6619c0e187ea
| | | |
| | | o  118 6606e146cd64
| | | |
| | | o  117 c4e618f32d28
| | | |
| | | o  116 883c8409769b
| | | |
| | | o  115 5a32e31270ec
| | | |
| | | o  114 11c11f414492
| | | |
| | | o  113 26e3ed4bb4e2
| | | |
| | | o  112 69d0491f07f2
| | | |
| | | o  111 a98e8743df92
| | | |
| | | o  110 51c87b196596
| | | |
o | | |  109 2bb83a7deb18
| | | |
o | | |  108 43024e54d940
| | | |
o---+ |  107 8572b030cf77
 / / /
| o |  106 bb4502305aca
| | |
| o |    105 d96d821b534d
| |\ \
| | o |  104 6df652a2a845
| | | |
| o | |  103 61e48dc0fc6c
| | | |
| o | |  102 4f2c74d7cb38
| | | |
| o | |  101 c091f79e3ee1
| | | |
| o | |  100 f679b65e1f40
| |\| |
| o---+  99 06d8b6c9d7da
|  / /
| o |    98 764f337b2d23
| |\ \
| | o |  97 5d8b6641c96a
| | | |
| +---o  96 3e495267e054
| | |
| o |  95 a6cdede98394
| |\|
| | o    94 e0236a8d6b13
| | |\
| | | o  93 87f48f3746c0
| | | |
| | | o    92 1d881d6a341e
| | | |\
| | | | o  91 0d9405042924
| | | | |
| o | | |  90 1fbb298ce546
| | | | |
| o | | |  89 d6c2355f6c0f
| | | | |
| o | | |  88 112eda049dba
| | | | |
| o | | |  87 b5d45823a972
| | | | |
| o | | |  86 52c5ad8063f8
| |\| | |
| | o | |  85 cc246f410aec
| | |\| |
| | o | |  84 f27b995bd9d9
| | | | |
| | o | |  83 03582181f1ec
| | | | |
| | o | |  82 ee517d8cde1f
| | | | |
| o | | |  81 665b6f344d6a
| | | | |
| o | | |  80 32ae89b79554
| | | | |
| o | | |  79 8b8273d4e5c0
| | | | |
| o | | |  78 ba7707b25625
| | | | |
| o | | |  77 4ea5979f0d9c
| | | | |
| o | | |  76 c611272c3d8f
| | | | |
| o | | |  75 d5b2ece5c63e
| | | | |
| o | | |  74 dc7696d61373
| | | | |
| o---+ |  73 ba8cfd6241ee
|  / / /
| | o |  72 63d6740cfca1
| | |\|
| | | o  71 10552c394128
| | | |
+-----o  70 ffe28df906ab
| | | |
| | | o  69 a019ddaf5c06
| | | |
o-----+  68 02a15134f0f0
 / / /
+---o  67 66ab16da1b2a
| | |
| | o  66 b142552eebfa
| | |
o | |  65 09e886012c7d
| | |
o | |    64 93e065498229
|\ \ \
| o | |  63 61eb3b218239
| | | |
| o | |  62 425e970e51af
| | | |
| o | |  61 363179609869
| | | |
| o | |  60 f5eb75689c2b
| | | |
+---o |  59 3c78ebd48f5c
| |  /
o | |  58 1de8ae72a17b
| | |
o---+  57 1860e0b3ddf7
| | |
| | o  56 09f986de06f3
| |/|
| | o  55 298378e863f7
| | |
o | |  54 c8845178c55a
| | |
o | |  53 a8607dca99af
|\| |
| o |  52 6847c83e2363
| |\|
| o |  51 a3dd42aa3e9a
| | |
o---+  50 d1b6240a07e9
 / /
| o  49 10be7348662e
| |
| o    48 5ff2ab9a49ee
| |\
| | o    47 77a3eadc61af
| | |\
| | | o  46 92df3efbff65
| | | |
| | | o    45 cca54c005934
| | | |\
| | | | o  44 103ea35092bd
| | | | |
| o | | |  43 abfcfd345f80
| |/ / /
| o | |    42 032d23dce3f2
| |\ \ \
| | o | |  41 8f703e23a4ee
| | | | |
| | o | |  40 4a8d9fadbfd6
| | |\| |
| | o | |  39 24e73033cb53
| | | | |
| o---+ |  38 9333c9cbac3b
|  / / /
| | o /  37 41b543af8a9b
| | |/
| | o    36 dc02ae1c67a9
| | |\
| | | o  35 1fe583f0ef45
| | | |
| | | o    34 d70bf0fe4f75
| | | |\
| | | | o  33 911970430832
| | | | |
| | | | o  32 9b7867c68866
| | | | |
| | | | o  31 bc70c0b86ea8
| | | | |
| | | | o    30 833ef7180cd3
| | | | |\
| | | | | o  29 7112cf0d3352
| | | | | |
| | o | | |  28 bde64f434ea4
| | |/ / /
| | o / /  27 f485e75cf5d4
| | |/ /
| | o |  26 9ee9ae5f2e88
| | | |
| | o |  25 d84755f11cbb
| | | |
| | o |  24 6b18f0bfd1ad
| |/| |
| o | |    23 a9e5b42c63f8
| |\ \ \
| | o | |  22 c418bc6aefd4
| | | | |
| +---o |  21 b18bee1030dd
| | |  /
| o---+  20 1f74cf1be5cb
| | | |
| | | o    19 aeb2ff3af383
| | | |\
+-------o  18 f5925021afc7
| | | |
| o---+  17 6537855915e4
|  / /
| | o  16 840f7a7e330f
| |/
| o  15 f7ef935faa2f
|/|
| o  14 764790125b62
| |
| o  13 d2dcd73d9969
| |
| o  12 7105b369799d
| |
o |    11 5899825e7281
|\ \
| o |  10 c44c5e16f610
| |/
o |  9 ce2bdb2e874f
| |
o |  8 5be3c02d3f6c
| |
o |  7 ccf737af4cf8
|/
o  6 bc52ab3333a6
|
o  5 0b7025c2ce5f
|
o  4 6b7507c691ac
|
o  3 dde8ba20c41a
|
o  2 b486cb6a5323
|
o  1 c25eb3375713
|
o  0 026059ab87d2
```

Comment: Possibly a bug? Show us output from ``hg glog``.

Comment: You can click on such a changeset and see if TortoiseHg lists any child changesets.

Comment: @seler I think you're right about a bug, but I'm afraid there is some sensitive information in the log output.

Comment: @Helgi when I click on the changeset (and then click "+" next to the changeset node below the graph) it behaves exactly as if the lines were connected.

Comment: @regularmike Use templates to remove the sensitive log information: `hg log --graph --template "{rev} {node|short}\n"` or similar. See `hg help template` for more info.

Comment: @shambulator I'm getting a graph option not recognized error. I just updated to version 2.2.2 of Mercurial. It works without the graph option but not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: @regularmike try hg glog instead of --graph

Comment: And make sure you have the [graphlog extension enabled](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension#Configuration). There's nothing to install; you should be able to do it from your TortoiseHg settings.

Comment: OK, just added it. I still see the unconnected lines right around rev 281 in the TortoiseHg workbench, but I don't see anything weird in the ASCII output there. Does anybody else?

Comment: Do the branches go on after that? Could it be that TortoiseHG just hides the line to save horizontal space?

Comment: If you look at the first image I posted, that might make sense for where it trails off going toward the green line, but on the left side it seems like there's no reason it shouldn't be connected. Supposedly there is a "compact graph" option that sacrifices graph accuracy for horizontal space, but I never purposely enabled it and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Could it mean that you've merged from one named branch into another but that the first branch still exists? So the trailing line without a dot indicates the tip of each named branch. Should be pretty easy to confirm if that's the case.